# Ler arquivo CSV para gerar um novo CSV com uma nova coluna

Tags: java, csv

Eu preciso ler um arquivo CSV com o seguinte formato:

```
agencia;conta;saldo;status  
0101;12225-6;100,00;A  
0101;12226-8;50,00;A
```

Após ler o arquivo, eu tenho um serviço que valida se foi feita uma atualização (colocando `true` ou `false`) e, necessariamente preciso gerar uma nova coluna, gerando um novo CSV. Eu consegui ler o arquivo, mas quando vou gerar o novo CSV, só consigo gravar o primeiro registro.

```
public void exportarParaCSV(Writer writer){
        try {
            Files.lines(Paths.get("arquivo.csv"))
                    .skip(1)
                    .map(linha -> linha.split(";"))
                    .map(coluna -> {
                        try {
                            if (!Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("arquivo.csv")).isEmpty()) {
                                try (CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {
                                    AssociadoResponse associadoResponse = new AssociadoResponse(coluna[0], coluna[1], coluna[2], coluna[3], receitaService.atualizarConta(coluna[0], coluna[1], coluna[2], coluna[3]));
                                    csvPrinter.printRecord(associadoResponse.getNroCoop(), associadoResponse.getNroConta(), associadoResponse.getSaldo(), associadoResponse.getStatus(), associadoResponse.isResposta());
                                    return associadoResponse;
                                } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    })
                    .forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("erro");
        }
    }
```

Como eu posso fazer para que eu percorra todo arquivo?
Segue exemplo gerado com o serviço acima:

```
0101,12225-6,"100,00",A,true
```

Answer (score 0):

Pra que chamar `readAllLines` dentro do `map`? Isso quer dizer que **para cada linha do arquivo**, você abre o mesmo arquivo de novo e lê todas as linhas, só pra pegar o tamanho (o que é bem ineficiente). Em vez disso, porque não faz um `for` na lista retornada por `readAllLines`?

Além disso, também não precisa criar o `CSVPrinter` toda hora (como está dentro do `map`, ele é recriado todas as vezes - uma para cada linha). Em vez disso, crie-o apenas uma vez e já escreva tudo que precisa nele.

Entendi que o arquivo de saída não vai ter o cabeçalho, e você só quer criá-lo se o CSV tiver alguma coisa, então poderia ser assim:

```java
List<String> linhas = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("arquivo.csv"));
if (!linhas.isEmpty()) { // só cria o arquivo se tiver linhas
    // escreve no arquivo
    try (CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {
        // processa todas as linhas aqui, em vez de criar o CSVPrinter toda hora
        for (int i = 1; i < linhas.size(); i++) { // pula a primeira linha (começa do 1 em vez do zero)
            String[] coluna = linhas.get(i).split(";");
            AssociadoResponse associadoResponse = new AssociadoResponse(coluna[0], coluna[1], coluna[2], coluna[3], receitaService.atualizarConta(coluna[0], coluna[1], coluna[2], coluna[3]));
            csvPrinter.printRecord(associadoResponse.getNroCoop(), associadoResponse.getNroConta(), associadoResponse.getSaldo(), associadoResponse.getStatus(), associadoResponse.isResposta());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // tratar erro (mostrar mensagem, etc)
    }
}
```

Ou, se quiser muito mesmo usar *streams*:

```java
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(arquivo));
     CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)) {
    lines.skip(1).forEach(line -> {
        String[] coluna = line.split(";");
        try {
            AssociadoResponse associadoResponse = new AssociadoResponse(coluna[0], coluna[1], coluna[2], coluna[3], receitaService.atualizarConta(coluna[0], coluna[1], coluna[2], coluna[3]));
            csvPrinter.printRecord(associadoResponse.getNroCoop(), associadoResponse.getNroConta(), associadoResponse.getSaldo(), associadoResponse.getStatus(), associadoResponse.isResposta());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // tratar erro (mostrar mensagem, etc)
        }
    });
}
```